# Find the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{m=1}^n \left(({1+\frac{m^3}{n^4}})^{1/8}-1\right).$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Evaluate
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{m=1}^n \left(\left({1+\frac{m^3}{n^4}}\right)^{1/8}-1\right).$$

All I can say it's goes to indefinity $\infty-\infty$ so I'm interested in general idea rather than an exact answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Use binomial theorem to get $$\left(1+\frac{m^{3}} {n^{4}} \right)^{1/8}-1=\frac{m^{3}} {8n^{4}} -\frac{7m^{6}} {128n^{8}} +\cdots$$ and then your answer is $1/32$.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how this helps? You'd get the series $\sum_m\left(\frac{m^3}{8n^4}+\ldots\right)$ but then where do you go from there?

Comment: @Jam: this is a hint and your question is genuine. The first term when summed from $m=1$ to $n$ tends to $1/32$ and rest of the terms when summed tend to $0$. Just note the familiar formula $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac{m^{k}}{n^{l}}=\frac{1}{l}\text{ if }l=k+1,0\text { if }l>k+1$$ ($k, l$ are positive integers).

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

Note that for $x\in [0,1]$,
$$0\leq \left(1+\frac{x}{8}\right)-(1+x)^{1/8}\leq x^2,$$
which implies that
$$0\leq \sum_{m=1}^n \bigl(({1+\frac{m^3}{8n^4}})-1\bigr)-\sum_{m=1}^n \bigl(({1+\frac{m^3}{n^4}})^{1/8}-1\bigr)\leq \sum_{m=1}^n \bigl(\frac{m^3}{n^4}\bigr)^2=\frac{1}{n^8}\sum_{m=1}^n m^6=\frac{O(n^7)}{n^8}.$$
By the [Squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), it follows that the desired limit is the same of
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{m=1}^n \bigl(({1+\frac{m^3}{8n^4}})-1\bigr)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{m=1}^n m^3}{8n^4}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^3}{8(n^4-(n-1)^4)}=\frac{1}{8\cdot 4}=\frac{1}{32}$$
where in the last step we used the [Stolz-Cesaro Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem).

Comment: For people (like me) confused about the use of Stolz Cesaro, if you set $a(n)=\frac14n^2(n+1)^2$ then $a(n)-a(n-1)=n^3$ so the limit we were looking for was $\frac18\lim\frac{a(n)-a(n-1)}{n^4-(n-1)^4}=\frac18\lim\frac{a(n)}{n^4}$.